# If $G=0$ on boundary $S$, then shouldn't $\int_S f \frac{\partial G}{\partial n} dS = 0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If function $G=0$ on boundary $S$, then shouldn't $\int_{S} f \frac{\partial G}{\partial n} dS = 0$? 
Here $n$ is an outward normal.

More details on this [here p. 57](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/chap4.pdf).

Or can the directional derivatives exist and be $\not = 0$, even if $G=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $S= \{x^n >0 \}$ and $G(x)= x_n$. Then $G=0$ on the boundary of $S$ but the normal derivative is  $\, -1$ .

Answer (score 1):

Think about the one-dimensional analogue: just because a function is zero at a point does not mean that its derivative is zero at that point. If we know a function is zero along some surface, we can conclude that its derivatives in directions *tangential* to the surface will be zero; but not normal.

Comment: What confused me is that surely $(0)'=0$.

Comment: Yes, but the first $0$ appearing there is the zero *function*, so you can only make this deduction if you know the function is zero everywhere nearby, not just at a single point (or in the higher-dimensional case along some low-dimensional subset). The function $f(x) =x$ is zero at the point $x=0$, but it's not the zero function and $f'(0)\ne 0$.